# How to transpose two characters in a textarea

Tags: javascript, textbox, google-chrome-extension

How can I get at the content of a text area and swap the two characters around the cursor, in Javascript? I want to write a tiny, but useful Chrome extension that will let me do this when I mistype in gmail. (I'm assuming that the the main editing area in gmail is a textarea).

This may be a question too stupid to ask here. In any case, I have searched for an answer and failed. I'm not a real programmer, but I have written snippets to do this in other scripting languages. It's easy enough to do it Firefox, for example, with an autohotkey script. For some reason the Javascript quite defeats me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the code in http://jsfiddle.net/Lg3Ng/

**HTML:**

```
<textarea id="my_text" onclick="changeChar();"></textarea>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function changeChar() {    
    var pos = getCaretPosition(document.getElementById("my_text"));
    //alert(pos);
    if (pos > 0) swapChars(pos - 1);
}

function swapChars(pos) {

    var cur_val = document.getElementById("my_text").value;

    var firstChar = cur_val.charAt(pos);
    var secondChar = cur_val.charAt(pos + 1);

    var startString = cur_val.substr(0, pos);
    var endString = cur_val.substring(pos + 2);

    document.getElementById("my_text").value = startString + secondChar + firstChar + endString;
}


// From http://demo.vishalon.net/getset.htm
function getCaretPosition(ctrl) {

    var CaretPos = 0;
    // IE Support
    if (document.selection) {

        ctrl.focus();
        var Sel = document.selection.createRange();

        Sel.moveStart('character', -ctrl.value.length);

        CaretPos = Sel.text.length;
    }
    // Firefox support
    else if (ctrl.selectionStart || ctrl.selectionStart == '0'){
        CaretPos = ctrl.selectionStart;
    }

    return (CaretPos);

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I'm sorry not to have replied earlier -- work got in the way.